# Do we put business rules in business use case diagram?

Tags: analysis

I wanna to draw a business use case diagram for a specified problem.
The problem has some rules. Now I wanna to ask that:
Is it correct to put business rules when drawing business use case?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is correct to add any information that makes your diagram easier to understand. If you can't find the proper diagram item for the information you want to include, use comments.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Konamiman that some flexibility in what we "should" do with our diagrams is reasonable, our objective is to communicate. In this particular situation I would have expected Business Rules to be a largely internal implementation feature of a system and so when we describe the Business Use cases (how the system is used) we probably don't need to mention them. "Approve Insurance Claim" may well be a use case for the system, and probably uses Business Rules internally, but does the reader of the diagram need to know that?

I can imagine that you may have additional "Change Business Rule" use case.